Postman - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNextRequest')
I have a webhook monitor created following the instructions in this video. Apparently, it works ok.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oxsdv1VFRsE
Given that, I want to use it to catch the payload sent by a webhook and then trigger another request in the same collection using some of that data. I decided to make a simple try out. I run the "Call webhook" request which only sends a very simple json body to the url webhook created with the request in the "Create webhook" folder. That webhook returns the payload and it is caught by a monitor that runs the "Echo the payload" request. May be my concepts are not perfect, but that is how I understand.

Calling the Step 1 request alone, works perfect, it creates something in the system and I get an Id. That is the result Iant at this moment. I want the "Echo the payload" request to hand over to "Step 1". I used this code in the post-response script of the "Echo the payload" request.
// stop the collection run
//postman.setNextRequest(null)

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

console.log("hello from the Test Script!", pm.collectionVariables.get("webhookData"))

console.log("about to run Step 1.");

pm.execute.setNextRequest("2311b468-9c9e-4a59-ad2a-e37d631c107c");

I am using the request ID, but it also behaves the same using the request name.
What I want is that when I call the webhook, and it sends the payload, the "echo the payload" request catches some data and calls the "Step 1" request. Currently I am not getting any data, just making sure I can call the "Sstep 1" request from the post-response script.
When I call the webhook, this is what is happening:

You can see it is reaching the monitor and running the pre request script and the test script (they changed that recently and is the now called post-response script). It is running the "about to run Step 1" log, but then throws an error I cannot figure out.
Then, even weirder, it is running the create webhook request, and then the call webhook again. Remember I used
pm.execute.setNextRequest("2311b468-9c9e-4a59-ad2a-e37d631c107c");
to control the test flow. It is taking so long to run because it is, apparently, entering an infinite loop.
I don´t know what TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNextRequest') means and how to solve it.
I expect it to handover to step 1 request.
UPDATE
I will post another question addressing the setNextRequest behavior. This question problem was mainly the code I was using.

Can you share your collection json file? It will help you get a solution.

Sadly I can’t because we are using critical information there, but I can solve anything you need to know to help me figure this out.

I realized the three requests of the webhook tutorial are somehow behaving differently. I realized too that the api key authorization was not correctly set, so I set it individually for each webhook request. Still cannot make it work again. The monitor is created when I run the webhook creation, but when I run the call to webhook, it just times out. I really don't know if it is a faulty tutorial, faulty collection or faulty me.

You need to change
From
pm.execute.setNextRequest("2311b468-9c9e-4a59-ad2a-e37d631c107c");

To
postman.setNextRequest("Echo the payload"); // Using name for calling a request


That part of the code is in the post-response script of “echo the payload”. You mean to call itself? Because what O want to do is to run “step 1” after “echo the payload”. Or do you mean, using the name instead of the id?

No call next Request. Not itself. You know the name

Behaves the same. I am updating the question to show how the monitor shows after calling the webhook.

Definitely, you have to use 'request name' instead of uuid. I verified in here. Your question no reproducible without your full collection file.

I'll try to duplicate it so I can share the collection. BTW, I just remove the setnextrequest and set it to null to stop running the collection. and it is also consuming a lot of time to get done. What I guess is happening is that the webhook is timing out and the code stops running and jumps to the next request in the collection.

Just for a FYI the correct syntax in the latest versions is pm.execution.setNextRequest() and postman.setNextRequest() will throw a deprecation warning in the postman.

You seems like using old version. My Postman v11.0.11 is the latest version. can you check your Postman version?

Thank you to Danny Dainton that pointed out that the code was not correct. That generated a lot of issues that were hard to track regarding the behaviour of the scripts.
The updated code fot the postman webhook tutorial is as follows.
For "Echo the payload" request Pre-request script:
// access the request body of the webhook
let previousRequest = JSON.parse(pm.globals.get("previousRequest")).data;

// previousRequest contains the data sent to your webhook.
console.log("hello from the Pre-request Script!", JSON.stringify(previousRequest));

// set a variable to persist this data throughout the request lifecycle (pre-request, request, and test)
pm.collectionVariables.set("webhookData", previousRequest)

And for the "Echo the payload" request post-response script:
// stop the collection run
pm.execution.setNextRequest(null);

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

console.log("hello from the Test Script!", pm.collectionVariables.get("webhookData"))

This way the webhook will run ok.

